# Matplotlib: Plotting all columns on the x-axis and values on the y-axis grouped by a third variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I have data that looks like this:

```
group    var1    var2    var3
0        0.6    0.001    0.11  
1       -0.36  -0.007   -0.066481
```

I want to create a dot graph where the 3 different variables form the x-axis and the y-axis represent the values in the data frame, with different symbols/colors for the dots depending on the group on the leftmost column.

I tried melting the data into the format

```
group var  value
0     var1 0.6
1     var1 -0.36
0     var2 0.001
1     var2 -0.007
0     var3 0.11
1     var3 -0.066481
```

But I was only able to make separate plots by variable instead of one big plot. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that plots based on two values and each group has specific color:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
data = {
    'group': [0, 1],
    'var1': [0.6, -0.36],
    'var2': [0.001, -0.007],
    'var3': [0.11, -0.066481]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Reshape the data using melt
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars='group', var_name='variable', value_name='value')

# Create the dot plot using seaborn
sns.set(style="ticks")
sns.stripplot(x='variable', y='value', hue='group', data=df_melted, dodge=True, size=10, palette="Set2")

# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel('Variable')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Dot Graph')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```